# Should I use async "all the way" for my GUI app?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm a substantial way through developing a sizeable WPF application that will control a sophisticated piece of hardware via serial comms. At the very bottom of the application "stack" I have a serial comms tier (utilising the .Net 'SerialPort' class). Reading and writing to the h/w device is a fundamental part of the system, utilised by many different areas of the business logic tier, often interspersed with complex scientific calculations and other such logic; these BLL methods are in turn called from all over the UI tier.

Currently, everything in the business logic tier, including the SerialPort reading and writing, is *synchronous*. The only time I use async/await is in the UI tier, typically when calling into the business logic. Here I'll wrap the call in `Task.Run()`, e.g.:-

```
private async void SomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => _someBLLService.TurnPumpOn());
}
```

This is a simple example that takes a matter of milliseconds. A more complex example would be starting a long-running process (again using the above technique); this business logic "service" will run for some seconds or minutes, collecting data from the hardware and performing other "control" functions during this time. Periodically it will broadcast data back to the UI for plotting on a chart (via a pubsub event aggregator framework). The above technique works well, allowing the UI to remain responsive while such business tier processes are taking place.

I've recently been considering going "async all the way", starting with the serial comms code (e.g. using `.ReadAsync`), but this would have repercussions across the system. Dozens (if not hundreds) of business logic methods would need to be refactored into async methods, right up to the UI tier. Here I would be able to simplify the above code slightly:

```
private async void SomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await _someBLLService.TurnPumpOn();
}
```

While I'm not averse to tackling large refactoring jobs, I'm wondering what the benefits really are. A lot of folks (like Stephen Cleary) advocate the "async all the way" solution, but the main goal appears to be to keep the UI responsive when calling a long-running BLL process, which my `Task.Run()` technique already does.

Comment: To clarify, "async all the way" is another way of saying "don't block on async code" - it only goes one way. In the case of a UI app, the primary benefit of async is responsiveness, and `await Task.Run` is a perfectly fine solution if that works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your app (presumably) is not under high load and is a GUI app the only reason to use async and await are productivity gains. Throughput and scalability do not enter the picture.

Therefore, do what is most convenient to you. This can very well be the `await Task.Run` pattern that you used in the sample code.

> but this would have repercussions across the system

Yes. Async has a noticeable productivity cost and it is infectious. Only do that if you can clearly articulate the benefits you reap from that choice. Here, the only benefit would be that your UI code is a few characters shorter. It's the difference between your two code snippets. The entire rest of the system gets worse.

Maybe you have been following the C# community and picked up the trend to go async all the way. Programmers are very prone to jump to magic solutions without understanding them. Many advocates of async cannot even articulate the concrete benefits they derive from it. There is a lot of group think as well. Do not base your decision on internet advice alone. Factor that in and check for yourself what makes sense.

Comment: It's just a desktop app now, but there are plans to use SignalR to expose certain BLL methods, e.g. for a smartphone client to provide limited control of the h/w device (no more than one or two clients). My understanding is that SignalR handles client connections asynchronously, so presumably still not a good enough reason for async throughout?

Comment: SignalR supports you returning a task to it. That task can just be `Task.FromResult` or any other way to create a "dummy" task. If there is no load there are no perf concerns. SignalR will *internally* use efficient socket IO and you benefit from that.